# Send Git commit diffs into gist file

Tags: git, github, git-diff, gist

I'm aware of the major functions that `gist` and `github` can offer even not an in-depth control of all commands.
Now I need to maintain some historical changes inot my git repository and What I'm lookin for is, Is there any automatic way (command) to push the git changes in some branch as a .diff into a gist file? Let's say I want to send a pull request in a gist file.
Actually I can get the .diff of some commit and copy paste the content into by-hand created gist file.

Any recommandations would be greately appreciated.
BR.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use one of the [gist CLI clients](https://gist.github.com/defunkt/370230#command-line). I can recommend the first one, written in Ruby.

1. Install the [gist](https://github.com/defunkt/gist) CLI client:

   ```
   gem install gist
   ```

   For OS X, you can install even from Homebrew:

   ```
   brew install gist
   ```
2. Associate it with your account (it doesn’t store your credentials, it just uses them to get an OAuth2 token):

   ```
   gist --login
   ```
3. Then you can simply create a gist from command line, for example:

   ```
   git diff <commit>..<commit> | gist -f foo.diff
   ```

   and it will give you URL of the created gist.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, you really pointed to what I'm actually looking for :)

Comment: This also preserves the coloring, which is hard to find.

Comment: Use `git log` to show the commit history and find the hashes to use in <commit>..<commit>